# JS Close window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Is there any way to close the browser window completely using js without receiving a prompt?
I mean a browser window that a user opened not a pop-up or anything else

Comment: Downvoter: down voting is for questions that are not clear or not constructive; though I don't agree with the idea of controlling my browser window, the question is quite clear and answerable.

Comment: If that was a capability of JavaScript quite a few people would become annoyed as they see some random site close all of their tabs.

Comment: In some browsers this will work: Open a new window in your browser. Paste the bold text that is at the bottom of this comment into your new window's address bar, and hit enter. **javascript:self.close();**

Comment: To everyone who is wondering why a developer might want to do this: Simple answer is "penetration tests". Often companies will insist on a clean pentest sheet and many pentest organizations are requesting that the browser closes on logout so as to clear the browser memory (a vulnerability against local adversaries). I don't agree with it either, but sometimes you don't have a choice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Basically, only a window that a script opened may be closed by a script.  Trying to do so (using the command `window.close()`) results in the error `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.`

There is a good reason for this.  If any script could close any window, malicious code could easily substitute a fake page for a legit page by loading the fake page in a background window then closing the main window.

Generally speaking, it is bad practice to try and force control of any actions that are usually the domain of your user.  This includes things like scroll bars, overall font size, confirmation windows (for printing, saving, closing), and size and state of open windows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is NO. Typically all browsers have mechanisms of configuring what to allow JavaScript code to do -- closing windows and/or resizing is one of them and by default is set to prompt (for closing) and deny for resizing. So unless the user has specifically configured a different level, you won't be able to avoid the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The only code that exists to close windows is window.close(). For anything else, you'll need superior previleges like the addons have.

Answer (score 0):

`window.close()` will close the current tab, and if it's the last tab of the browser, it *might* close the whole browser window, too.